# How to configure Spring Cloud Configuration Server without the git profile?

Tags: spring-cloud-config-server

I'm attempting to run Spring Cloud Configuration Server, working through the examples in a book (Manning's *Spring Microservices in Action*), but updating to the latest versions: Java 17, spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.1, with Spring Cloud 2021.0.0-RC1.

Each time I try to start the server, I get this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you have set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.
```

I am not using the `git` profile. I have tried two different profiles: `native` (with config files on the classpath) and `vault` (with a Hashicorp Vault server running locally).  My latest `/src/resources/bootstrap.yml` contains the following:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: config-server
    profiles:
        active: vault
    cloud:
        config:
            server:
                vault:
                    port: 8200
                    host: 127.0.0.1
                    kvVersion: 2
server:
    port: 8071
```

My best guess is that the `bootstrap.yml` file isn't getting picked up at server startup, and perhaps the `git` profile is a default.  How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it looks like the problem here is that newer versions of Spring Cloud Configuration Server don't look for the `bootstrap.yml` file by default.  There are a few different ways to solve it.  The easiest is just to move all the properties to an `application.yml`/`application.properties` instead.

Another alternative is (found at NEWBEDEV [here](https://newbedev.com/bootstrap-yml-configuration-not-processed-anymore-with-spring-cloud-2020-0)) is to include a dependency that implements the "legacy" bootstrap behavior:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following into application.properties file.

spring.application.name=techefx-spring-cloud-config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/techefx/environment-variable-repo.git
server.port= ${port:8888}

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link below:

[Spring Cloud Config File System Backend Issue (not reading properties from the file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081637/spring-cloud-config-file-system-backend-issue-not-reading-properties-from-the-f/74658361#74658361)